# Looking for more info on SNMP v3 Traps in Junos

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex, juniper-mx, snmpv3

I have a customer requirement where I need to be able to have Junos Space Network Management Platform be able to modify the severity of snmp traps on our routers and switches. So first I am trying to figure out if traps can even be modified to have a different severity. I've googled as best I could, but I can't find any Juniper documentation that shows how to or if this is even possible. I've also logged into one of our MX204 routers and have tried to just "?" it and try to figure it out, but I can't seem to find any way to do so. It made me wonder if this was even possible and if SNMP traps are standardized in some RFC some where. I looked at [RFC 1157](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1157), but it didn't really talk about severity standardization. I'm wondering if it is possible to do this. For example, could I change a particular interface to just a warning severity if it goes down. Thanks for any help.

Comment: SNMP trap severity is not standardized as certain events may mean different things to different networks. Each vendor will have defaults for each event, but it's considered best practice for the NMS to do the alarm processing (severity interpretation, etc.). Juniper _technically_ has methods to accomplish this, but trust me when I say it's a simpler and more robust solution to use the NMS properly.

Comment: I recall coming across a document where it talked about changing the severity of the jnx traps, but it seemed to require code modification. That is definitely something we would not want to do. The problem we're facing is that it's a customer requirement. We can definitely let them know that it's normally best practice to us the NMS for severity interpretation and we can request relief from the requirement. Thanks Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

See Jordan's comment:

*SNMP trap severity is not standardized as certain events may mean different things to different networks. Each vendor will have defaults for each event, but it's considered best practice for the NMS to do the alarm processing (severity interpretation, etc.). Juniper technically has methods to accomplish this, but trust me when I say it's a simpler and more robust solution to use the NMS properly. –
Jordan Head*